# puppeteer addStyleTag css not injecting

Tags: javascript, css, typescript, puppeteer

I'm trying to inject this stylesheet into the puppeteer page, but it doesn't actually apply(Promise rejects). The css file is saved in the same directory as the scraping file. I have also tried implementing the css directly using 'content: '.

## scrape.ts

```
    await page.addStyleTag({ path: 'style.css' });
```

## style.css

```
div.bp-desktopLGPlus .page-container {
  width: 100%;
}

div.wrapper {
  width: 48%;
  display: inline-table;
  margin: 0% 1% 0% 1%;
}

.PageLayout__RightAside {
  display: none;
}

.Wrapper.Card__Content {
  width: 100%;
}

div#gamepackage-news {
  display: none;
}

.tertiary-nav-container {
  display: none;
}

.table__TD {
  font-size: 120% !important;
}
```

Comment: This doesn't seem like a [mcve]. The code looks totally fine taken out of context. Please [edit] the post to show code that I can run and see the problem. Thanks.

Comment: Update: the issue was with typescript and how it builds, so I needed to change the path to src/style.css